Ways to create a login using nodejs
So i am learning nodejs i am trying to create a login
here what I made so far it works
it connects to mongodb and check if the field if same then changing the allow variable to true
any ways to create a login i feel this is so wrong
let allow = false

app.get("/login", async (req, res) =>{  
  if(allow){
    return res.redirect("/")
  }

  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html")
})

app.post("/login", async(req, res) => {
  if(allow){
    return res.redirect("/")
  }

const userList = await USER_MODEL.findOne({ name: req.body.username })

  if(userList.name === req.body.username){
    console.log('THEREs user with that name')
    // console.log(userList.password)
    if(userList.password === req.body.password){
      console.log('yayaay')
      allow = true
      return res.redirect("/")
    }
    console.log('wrong')
  }else{
    console.log('not success')
  }
  console.log(userList)
  console.log(req.body.password)
  console.log(userList.password)

res.redirect("/login")
})


app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  // check if true
  if(!allow){
    return res.redirect("/login")
  }
})


You can improve your approach by using sessions or JWTs to manage user authentication state. You can try "express-session" library to manage user sessions, avoiding the use of global state for authentication.

For the love of all that is good in programming, do not store plain text passwords. Use a library like bcrypt to hash passwords before storing them in your database. Also instead of using a global variable to track login status, use sessions. This will allow you to keep track of individual users.

Hi, Surely you are learning a lot. The code at present is perfect. Now when we think about the improvements, the first point may be, how to make this system accessible to more than one user. Since the system at present handles only one user. Once one user has been validated and allow = true is set, when another person if tries to login, then that new login will automatically assumed validated and accordingly routed to the root route. This is the improvement you may need to think through next. Anyways, Good coding, keep on doing.

You can improve it in other ways though

Try using session or JWT for authenticating users
Also, hash your password for security purposes
You can also use try/catch for proper error handling

A better version of your code will be
Install jwt and hashing library
npm install jsonwebtoken bcrypt

Then you can implement the logic with the libraries
// JWT secret key
const JWT_SECRET = "yourSecretKey";

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/login.html");
});

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    const user = await USER_MODEL.findOne({ name: username });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send("User not found");
    }

    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!match) {
      return res.status(400).send("Invalid password");
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1h" });

    res.json({ token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});
                                      


it only return me a json when i go to the the protected route it only gives me unauthorize.

how do  i use that json for
